# CSS Code Issue with any version lower than IE8. Background images won't load. Any Ideas?

Tags: css

Background codes:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
  background:url(head1.gif) no-repeat top, url(water2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-color:#fff;
  font-family:"lucida sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#fff;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

p {
  line-height:1.5;
  padding-bottom:12px;
```

Comment: Those versions of IE don't support multiple background images.

Comment: Are you trying to load two background images on the same element? If so, the solution is not to use < IE9.  See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html#multiple

Comment: Just FYI, your URLs are best in quotes.  It's like pie with ice cream.

Comment: Mmm, yes. Quotes and ice cream are delicious.

Comment: That's how my browser feels about quotes.  It's drooling right now, just from us talking about it.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple backgrounds are CSS3, try 2 spans positioned over each other, with the backgrounds on each ( don't give them both a background color though )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the images show, but you could try putting one background image on the HTML element and leave the other on the body, making sure they share the same properties values for - width, margin, padding etc.